# How to solve Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' error in setAttribute() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function which dynamically updates a HTML `aria-expanded` attribute to true or false. However when I type `element` as `HTMLElement`, I receive a `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

```
  expandEotyDocumentsPanel(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.eotyExpanded = !this.eotyExpanded;
    element.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.eotyExpanded);
  }
```

As you might have already noticed, `this.eotyExpanded` is a boolean.

With regards to the second argument of `setAttribute()`, the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) say:

> A DOMString containing the value to assign to the attribute. Any non-string value specified is converted automatically into a string.

So I thought supplying a boolean value would be fine.

How can I suppress this error?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try out [Boolean.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

attribute of the element can't be a boolean, so you would probably just turn it into string instead with

`new Boolean(this.eotyExpanded).toString()`